# FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'col_definition'

Tags: sql-server-2012, sp-blitz, sp-blitzfirst

looking for some help.  I have just started looking at the Blitz stats but getting the following error.  This is whilst running sp_BlitzIndex. I am using Version 7.2 (dated 28/01/2019).

> FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'col_definition' because
>   it contains a character (0x001F) which is not allowed in XML. To
>   retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or
>   image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

Is there any easy way to fix this or is it a case of adding a number of replace statements to remove invalid characters?

It looks like the error is triggering at the start of Step 2 (line 1667). The specific section of code is but I think the following lines would also have the same issue.

```
RAISERROR (N'Updating #IndexSanity.key_column_names',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;
UPDATE    #IndexSanity
SET        key_column_names = D1.key_column_names
FROM    #IndexSanity si
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT  RTRIM(STUFF( (SELECT  N', ' + c.column_name 
                            + N' {' + system_type_name + N' ' + CAST(max_length AS NVARCHAR(50)) +  N'}'
                                AS col_definition
                            FROM    #IndexColumns c
                            WHERE    c.database_id= si.database_id
                                    AND c.schema_name = si.schema_name
                                    AND c.object_id = si.object_id
                                    AND c.index_id = si.index_id
                                    AND c.is_included_column = 0 /*Just Keys*/
                                    AND c.key_ordinal > 0 /*Ignore non-key columns, such as partitioning keys*/
                            ORDER BY c.object_id, c.index_id, c.key_ordinal    
                    FOR      XML PATH('') ,TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))
                                ) D1 ( key_column_names );
```